# How do you define an array in python whose input is a binary counter?

Tags: python, numpy

Wrote this script to create a 4x16 matrix for all possible combinations of 4 bits:

```
import numpy as np
    a = []
    for x in range(2):
        for y in range(2):
            for z in range(2):
                for w in range(2):
                 a.append([x,y,z,w])
    a = np.array(a)
    print(a)
```

Output

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

It works.. however it's 4 loops for 4 bits. Raising the number of bits means more loops, does anyone have another way of doing this?

Haven't tried much.. new to programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with just `numpy`,we can use `np.unpackbits`

```
bits = 4
np.unpackbits(np.arange(2**bits, dtype=np.uint8)[...,None], count=bits, axis=1, bitorder='little')
```

Comment: Works for 4 bits since 4^2 = 2^4 in this case, but if I change the bit number to 7, I get a (7^2, 7) matrix instead of a (2^7, 7) matrix

Comment: i edited, it should be 2**bits in arange

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
list(itertools.product(range(2), repeat=4))
```

Here `range(2)` provides the `0` and `1`, and then `repeat=4` says 4 bits. If you want 20 bits, use `repeat=20`.

This result actually gives you a `list`, but if you want to iterate through each option one at a time, just use `itertools.product(range(2), repeat=4)` on its own, as this gives you a generator. For larger numbers of bits, the number of combinations might not fit in memory. Using the generator version means you only ever have one combination in memory at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```
def create_matrix(n, arr=[]):
    if n == 0:
        print(arr)
    else:
        for i in range(2):
            create_matrix(n-1, arr + [I])
```

output:

```
> create_matrix(4)
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

This can be used to generate a matrix for all possible combinations of any bits.

It appends a `0` or `1` to `arr` and passes it on to the next recursive call until `n` leads to `0`. When `n` becomes `0`, it prints out `arr`.

---

**UPDATE**

As @Pranav Hosangadi suggestions, I've modified the code to get rid of mutable default argument and to has the return statement.

```
def create_matrix(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [[i] + item for i in range(2) for item in create_matrix(n-1)]
```

---

P.S. It is good to learn about ***Recursion***.

Comment: Beware the mutable default argument (doesn't really matter in this case because you don't modify it in the function)

Comment: Also a function that builds something should return it instead of just printing it.